# How to publish a photo to a Facebook page as a separate story

Tags: facebook, api

If I use the Facebook API to publish a photo to a page they appear as single story.

```pl
$args = array(
        'message' => '',
);
$args["picture"] = '@' . realpath($file);
$ch = curl_init();

$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token='.$token;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

If I publish from Facebook they appear correctly as a single story for each picture.
How to do this programmatically?